# An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'server_name' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update event_alerts table using stored procedure as below:

```
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[servermatch_servers]
@server_name varchar(25)
as
update event_alerts 
set event_alerts.status_alert = (case when master_serverlist.Server_list is null then '0' else '1' 
end)
from event_alerts inner join master_serverlist  on master_serverlist.Server_list = 
event_alerts.server_name where server_name = @server_name
```

c# code blow:

```
using (SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("servermatch_servers", conn1))
{
command3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@server_name", server);
command3.Parameters[@"server_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Value of server is extracted from string which is the value of server_name
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a typo cause it should be `command3.Parameters["@server_name"]`

Comment: server is a string value of server_name

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: sql is used for this

Answer (score 0):

I think below line is the culprit -

```
command3.Parameters[@"server_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Try changing it to

```
command3.Parameters["@server_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```